# PHP - Releasing resultset

Tags: php, resultset

I've been looking online and every article I've come across seems to say something slightly different. If I'm working with a resultset and the program exits before releasing the results what exactly happens?

Is there a better way to ensure that it always happens? The same goes for database connections.

```
    if($statement->fetch()) {
        exit("Result!");
    }

    $statement->free_result();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `free_result` tells the database engine it can release the result set.

It only needs to be called if you are concerned about how much memory is being used for queries that return large result sets. All associated result memory is automatically freed at the end of the script's execution.

You can use `register_shutdown_function` to make sure your results are freed from memory

```
function shutdown(){
    global $statement;
    if($statement){
        $statement->free_result();
    }
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) in PHP to make sure that a function / a lot of functions fire on exit. In your example, you could also change the if statement to the following:

```
$exitResult = null;
if($statement->fetch()) {
    $exitResult = "Result!";
}

$statement->free_result();
if ($exitResult !== null) exit($exitResult);
```

It should be noted though, that most plugins/extensions (that connects to databases etc.) clean up after themself after shutdown of the PHP process (on the end of a script).

If you use this in a class, you can save the reference to `$statement` and then use a [`__destruct`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor) function in the class.